# Filter a pivot table using VBA when the filter is nested and not the top tier

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm not able to filter a pivot table using VBA when the filter is a sub tier of a main filter item. I get a Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

I can do it for the main filter tier, but not if there are additional subcategories within the initial filter item.

```
Sub Pull_Volume()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim main As Worksheet
Dim dte As String
Dim dteFld As PivotField

Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set pt = main.PivotTables("PivotTable$A$1")
Set dteFld = pt.PivotFields("[Date].[Hierarchy].[Quarter]")

dte = ("[Date].[Hierarchy].&[2019-Q2]")

With dteFld
    .CurrentPageName = dte
End With

End Sub
```

Line 15 throws the

> Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

If I set line 10 to :

```
Set dteFld = pt.PivotFields("[Date].[Hierarchy].[Year]")
```

And line 12 to:

```
dte = ("[Date].[Hierarchy].&[2019]")
```

This works and I filter on 2019.
If I try to filter on Q2 which is one of 4 nested sub filters within 2019 (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) I get the error. I assume I need to do some kind of simultaneous filtering on 2019 and then 2019-Q2 or use some kind of array but it's a bit beyond me.